# In this case, no problem for initializing weights in deep learning networks to 0

Tags: neural-networks, symmetry

Deep learning textbooks say that initializing all weights of neural networks to 0 will be problematic as it
*breaks symmetry*.  I tried with a simple 1-layer neural network but found
such is not the case, as shown below. Can anyone help clarify?

Consider a DL network composed of an input layer and an output layer, [image: li]

Suppose that a simplified loss function looks like

$$L= (w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 - y)^2 + (w_1' x_1 + w_2' x_2 - y')^2$$

where $y$ and$y'$ are expected results for the two units in the output layer. We ignored activation functions.

We got 
$\partial L/\partial w_1 = 2 y x_1$, and
$\partial L/\partial w_1' = 2 y' x_1$

So, there does not seem to have "breaking symmetry" issue in this case, unless $y=y'$.  Where am I wrong, or is this case not general enough?

Answer (score 0):

This particular network is a special case of a neural network. It has 0 hidden layers, so it is an ordinary regression problem, except with two target (output) features instead of the more typical 1 target. Under certain conditions, regression is a strongly convex optimization problem.

The strong convexity of the regression problem implies that the optimal parameter configuration to this network is not sensitive to the choice of initial guess.

**A note on terminology:** It's typical for a neural network to have 1 or more hidden layers. In particular, the distinguishing characteristic of "DL" (deep learning) models is that they have *many* hidden layers. The large number of hidden layers is what makes them "deep" as opposed to "shallow." The statement about "breaking symmetry" should be read with this in mind.